# Why does Facebook SDK for iOS 6 fail on some users but succeed on others?

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on

Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 is implemented in my app, and yet I've been using SSO, for the sake that it was easier to understand.

Now I am implementing the portions of the Facebook SDK that support iOS 6 Facebook account integration.

I'd like to know what's anyone's first thoughts about the problem after seeing this process:

```
On the simulator
sign into my facebook account in Settings app
switch back to my app
sign in with facebook account
handler for openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions gets state FBSessionStateOpen
everything works.

switch back to settings app
remove my account
sign in with facebook test user account
switch back to my app
sign in with facebook account
handler for openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions gets state FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed
```

Before implementing the portion of Facebook SDK for iOS 6 integration, the Single-Sign-On worked perfectly, 100% of the time for the facebook test user account.

Is there any reason the iOS 6 integration will fail 100% on specific users where the SSO implementation works 100% for the same users?
Another final note: where my app appears in the list in Settings > Facebook, it is turned on/enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I experienced the same issue. The core seems to be the fact that when you have FB credentials in the settings app, Facebook uses one route to authenticate. When you remove it, FB checks against the stored settings and fails and returns a close-state. It was expecting to be able to use the session but that was destroyed.

Keep in mind in a real-world setting, your user is not going to be toggling between the setup that way. It is very disconcerting when you are testing various scenarios on your device, but a real-world user is not going to attempt different user logins or different user-credential on/off scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for that, yes the note you mention to keep-in-mind is always there in my mind :)   But the note about Facebook expecting to use a session but that was destroyed, what is this all about? How is facebook expecting to use a session when one is not logically supposed to be active?

Comment: After reading your message a 3rd time, I wonder:  is a session supposed to be opened for all authorized apps at the moment of Settings > Facebook sign-in, and persist beyond the app launch and termination?  Or perhaps, a session is supposed to be opened within the app and persist within iOS's account store, beyond the app termination?  But I'm confused why it would fail 100%. How can a session actually be opened, ever???

Comment: I use closeAndClearTokenInformation on the FBSession.activeSession when the handler receives state FBSessionStateClosed or FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed.  Don't know if that's actually hindering the Settings.

Comment: Tokens are on a per-app basis and so that shouldn't have a bearing. The session can persist outside your app launch not sure if the framework keeps it around in some cache.

Comment: I don't know if this relevant, you may have had the same error code: FBErrorLoginFailedOrCancelled, error code 2.  I hate having to rely on the Facebook SDK especially since it is closed source.  In Facebook SDK 2.6, I could step through and find out where the decision was made if the login is fail or success.  The Settings > Facebook sign-in with the test user succeeds by showing checkmarks after tapping "Sign In".  A fake password and iOS spits out a failure alert message.  So, I feel like my hands are tied.

Comment: I should also make note, this isn't specific to my app and my code.  This happens with the Scrumptuous sample app.

Comment: My take on FB stuff - not very well baked. I literally went nuts trying to setup an "application page" on FB for my app. I was presented a page with PHP script segments and was asked to press links that didn't exist!

Comment: I'm seriously thinking of removing the facebook iOS 6 integration from this app, since single-sign-on has been reliable so far, and the app must support iOS 5.

Comment: #@#$\@%!!.  I did a google search just now to see if I could find any new information on this problem, and I found this SO question, thought it'd be awesome, then found it's my own un-answered question.